# Clicking the Button will move to the next controller?

Tags: swift, xcode, button, viewcontroller

**How to Move to the Next Controller with a single click of a Button?** 
There is no data transfer, only one click of button and it will proceed to the next controller.

I created a controller named "ViewIntro" which is the initial controller. It's basically a Welcome Screen and there is a button at the bottom.

Once the button is clicked, it will proceed to the viewController which is the original controller whenever we start an xcode project ***I forgot to make the viewController as my welcome screen***

Anyways, here is my current code of my ViewIntro:

`import Foundation
    import UIKit

```
class ViewIntro : UIViewController{

   @IBOutlet weak var btnEnter: UIButton!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
   super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   }`
```

I also had connected the ViewIntro to ViewController through identifier as shown in the attached image. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click your button and drag it to your controller. Just like creating an `IBOutlet` but you should select Action mode. Afret creating an `IBAction` for your button, just add this code into it:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showMain", sender: nil)
```

Comment: You sir made me smile. I'm beginner with swift and was really having difficulty solving this. Thank you sir. Few minutes and I can mark your answer correct. :)

Comment: It's same as your btnEnter creation. But after dragging it to your controller, you should select the _Connection_ as Action, not Outlet. It will create an action function for your button. :)

Comment: Yes, thank you it works now. Thank you very much sir! :)